# MySQL For Excel e opções para importar tabela Excel no MySQL

Tags: mysql, microsoft-excel

Estou tentando importar um banco de dados que está no formato do Excel para o MySQL.

Estava tentando com MySQL For Excel, lançado mesma empresa.

Como podem ver na imagem abaixo ele já está instalado:

[image]

No meu Excel não aparece nada,no exemplo que tem no site oficial era para aparecer onde está a caixinha preta:

[image]

Será preciso fazer alguma configuração extra?
Existe outra alternativa além dessa?

Comment: Arquivo > Opções > Suplementos > Suplementos COM, verifica se a opção do MySQL For Excel esta na lista e se está marcada @Rodolfo Oliveira

Comment: Particularmente eu não gosto dessa ferramenta, prefiro importar via comando `LOAD DATA INFILE`, ou quando preciso criar a tabela quando se tem várias colunas uso o site http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm

Comment: Algum motivo especial para não gostar do MySQL for Excel?